# Error while accessing SQL Server using Visual studio 2010

Tags: sql-server

I am getting an error while trying to create a database using Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2010.

I checked SQL Server configuration manager and found that SQL service is not running, but when I am trying to start it; its not starting :(

Please guide me solution for this, I've figured out that I may have disabled some windows service required to run SQL Server (while optimizing WinXP after installing it some months ago).

Screenshot1:

[image]

Screenshot2:

[image]

Comment: Open your event viewer and check what errors sql server is writing there. These error don't tell enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Yep, please check the screenshot http://i.imgur.com/udyuf.jpg

Comment: Seems you deleted your master database. Now that is going to hurt a bit.

Comment: But I haven't created one yet :o How do I fix it?

Comment: Well then it just a bad installation. If you are starting fresh, why not just reinstall SqlServer?

Comment: I re-installed the Visual studio ultimate (it had sqlserverexpress08 with it), should I install SqlServer08 separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error it is clear that your master database file of SqlServerExpress is corrupted.

Since this is a new installation, it would be best to uninstall and reinstall SqlServerExpress.

If you have a copy of SqlServer, installing that would solve the problem too.

If you do not want to reinstall, the master database can be rebuilt.

From [how to rebuild master database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143269.aspx):

> Use of the Setup command to rebuild the master database has changed in
>   this Microsoft SQL Server release. Run Setup.exe to rebuild, verify,
>   and repair a SQL Server instance, and rebuild the system databases.
>   This procedure is most often used to rebuild the master database for a
>   corrupted installation of SQL Server.